# Web scraping using python can't find the weblink

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am new to web scraping using python. I have successfully learned to scrape information from some of the websites for example https://www.jameda.de and wikipedia. But I have come across a website that doesn't open up a new weblink when searched for a specific data. I am unable to understand how to scrape this website. Any help is much appreciated.

Website:
https://www.kvwl.de/earzt/index.htm

In the search fields you could input for example "Berlin, Germany" in (Ihr Standort) field and look at the web address, it doesn't change. Also I looked in the inspect field, I can't see any link to scrape the data.

Any help is very much appreciated!!

below is the code I have used to extract information from other website:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag
import urllib.request
import re
base_site = "https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/Suche_SN/index.js?a=DL&Otn1=798&Ic1=127&Ftg=33014+Bad+Driburg&Ftg_e=&Lng=36"
response = requests.get(base_site)
response.status_code
html = response.content
html

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
with open('TK_33014_Bad_Driburg_LXML.html','wb') as file:
    file.write(soup.prettify('utf-8'))

divs = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "card dl"})

headings = [div.find('a').text for div in divs]
headings
```

Comment: let me guess: headings is `empty` and divs is `empty`.

Comment: you may need to use `selinium `

Comment: Thank you Ajay for the hint. I will look into it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site uses JavaScript for the search and BeautifulSoup only parses the HTML.

So here are two things you can do to scrape a page like this:

- use something that drives a headless browser (without a GUI), which actually executes the Javascript. You can then simulate typing into text fields and clicking buttons. `selenium` is an option for this as pointed out in the comments. Coming from more of a JavaScript background, I prefer `puppeteer`, which also seems to have [a Python port](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/) (haven't tried it with Python yet, though) or `playwright`.
- reverse engineer the page requests: if you open Chrome devtools to the network tab on the page you linked, search for something and select the "XHR" tab (for XML HTTP requests done by JavaScript) as seen in the screenshot, you can see the page that is being requested, as well as the parameters. You can even right click it and copy the request as a `curl`, `fetch` and many more.
  [image: devtools screenshot]

Here's the request as a JavaScript fetch:

```
fetch("https://www.kvwl.de/DocSearchService/DocSearchService/searchDocs", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin"
  },
  "referrer": "https://www.kvwl.de/earzt/index.htm",
  "referrerPolicy": "same-origin",
  "body": "{\"Latitude\":52.52000659999999,\"Longitude\":13.404954,\"DocGender\":\"\",\"DocNamePattern\":\"\",\"ExpertiseAreaStructureId\":\"\",\"ApplicableQualificationId\":\"\",\"SpecialServiceId\":\"\",\"LanguageId\":\"\",\"BarrierFreeAttributeFilter\":{\"ids\":[]},\"PageId\":0,\"PageSize\":20}",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "omit"
});
```

You can then request this URL directly in your script, pass the necessary variables into the body and you should get a JSON response with the answer.